# Batch file doubts

Tags: vxworks, batch-processing

I have a .bat file shown below in which I want to redirect the whole contents present in my IDE to some text file.

```
D:\WindRiver\wrenv.exe -p vxworks653-2.2.3 run
D:\WindRiver\wrenv.exe -p vxworks653-2.2.3>C:\ThreePartition\output.txt 
PAUSE
```

I am able to just get some partial output i.e I am unable to get the errors which are thrown during compilation or building process.
Is this correct or Can anyone suggest any other way??

Thanks a lot
Maddy

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: 
D:\WindRiver\wrenv.exe -p vxworks653-2.2.3 > C:\ThreePartition\output.txt 2>&1

You can find a good explanation [here](http://programing-fun.blogspot.com/2008/04/redirecting-standard-error-output-in.html). Basically you need to redirect both stdout AND stderr to your file.

Best regards.

Comment: Hey maurico,Thanks a lot buddy,but i see another bottleneck i.e the IDe is running in the background,But i am able to get the whole contents into the text file successfully.I want my IDE to run in the forefront too.

Comment: Hey mauricio,
        Thats not running in the forefronti mean my IDE.Can u plz suggest me any alternative answer??

Comment: I am very unsure about this but can you try following 

D:\WindRiver\wrenv.exe -p vxworks653-2.2.3 -o run > C:\ThreePartition\output.txt 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

Your batch is redirecting all messages from wrenv.exe that are sent to the standard output.

I never used WinRiver but usually IDEs manage the console internally and don't log any messages on the standard output/error stream.

It is maybe possible to set the output of the console of the IDE though. If it is, try to set it to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to combine both those lines into one:

```
D:\WindRiver\wrenv.exe -p vxworks653-2.2.3 run >C:\ThreePartition\output.txt
```

OK, looking at your posts [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-files-redirection/18654.html), [here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-87872-extraction-of-output-from-an-ide-into-text) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/ccnet-user/browse_thread/thread/b5742af3ff9eda42), it seems you want to log the compilation process.  The command for that will be something like (all on one line):

```
make ThreePartition.mak >C:\ThreePartition\output.txt
```

Assuming there's a file called ThreePartition.mak.

The command you've been using so far is designed to simply open an interface where you can type commands, which is why you get no output.  If you want to log simulation, or a kernel build, there is a file called `vxworks_cli_tools_users_guide_6.6.pdf` which describes the command line interface, including `vxprj` in full detail.

Also, are you really using a nant script to call a .vbs to call a .bat to call wrenv.exe? I'm sure there's a simpler way to do that.

Comment: But tats not at all working Mark.I had tried that too.is der any other way??